# is there an efficient way to iterate trough all ndarray elements

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

My problem is that i have a ndarray of shape (N,M,3) and i am trying to check each element in the array using a low level approach currently i am doing something like:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        if ndarr[i][j][2] == 3:
           ndarr[i][j][0] == var1
```

and most of the time the ndarray i need to process is very large usually around 1000x1000 .

the same idea i managed to run on cpp withing a couple of milisecondes in python it take around 30 seconds at best.

i would really appreciate if someone can explain to me or point me towards reading material on how to efficiently iterate trough ndarray

Comment: NumPy efficiency depends on *avoiding* this kind of explicit iteration - you need to use NumPy routines that iterate over the array buffer internally. Python-level loops will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that *efficiently*.

NumPy is a small Python wrapper around C code/datatypes. So an ndarray is actually a multidimensional C array. That means the memory address of the array is the address of the first element of the array. All other elements are stored consecutively in memory.

What your Python `for` loop does, is grabbing each element of the array and temporarily saving it somewhere else (as a Python datastructure) before stuffing it back in the C array. As I have said, there is no way of doing that efficiently with a Python loop.

What you could do is using Numba `@jit` to speed up the `for` loop or look after a NumPy routine, that can iterate over an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use logical indexing to do this more efficiently, it might be interesting to see how it compares with your c implementation.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(2, 4, 3)
print(a)

idx = a[:, :, 2] > 0
a[idx, 0] = 9

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Numpy you have to use vectorized-commands (usually calling a C or Cython-function) to achieve good performance. As an alternative you can use Numba or Cython.

**Two possible Implementations**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def calc_np(ndarr,var1):
    ndarr[ndarr[:,:,0]==3]=var1
    return ndarr

@nb.njit(parallel=True,cache=True)
def calc_nb(ndarr,var1):
    for i in nb.prange(ndarr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(ndarr.shape[1]):
            if ndarr[i,j,2] == 3:
                ndarr[i,j,0] == var1
    return ndarr
```

**Timings**

```
ndarr=np.random.randint(low=0,high=3,size=(1000,1000,3))

%timeit calc_np(ndarr,2)
#780 µs ± 6.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#first call takes longer due to compilation overhead
res=calc_nb(ndarr,2)
%timeit calc(ndarr,2)
#55.2 µs ± 160 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**Edit**

You also use a wrong indexing method. `ndarr[i]` gives a 2d view on the original 3d-array, the next indexing operation `[j]` gives the next view on the previous view. This also has quite an impact on performance.

```
def calc_1(ndarr,var1):
    for i in range(ndarr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(ndarr.shape[1]):
            if ndarr[i][j][2] == 3:
                ndarr[i][j][0] == var1
    return ndarr

def calc_2(ndarr,var1):
    for i in range(ndarr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(ndarr.shape[1]):
            if ndarr[i,j,2] == 3:
                ndarr[i,j,0] == var1
    return ndarr

%timeit calc_1(ndarr,2)
#549 ms ± 11.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit calc_2(ndarr,2)
#321 ms ± 2.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```